# Use Task.Run or ContinueWith after HttpListener,GetContextAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, httplistener

What is the difference (if any) between the following:

```
_listener = new HttpListener();

// Wait for an incoming request, then start a new task
// that executes ProcessContext()
var httpctx = await _listener.GetContextAsync();
await Task.Run(() => ProcessContext(httpctx));

/* -- or -- */

// Use ContinueWith to pass the incoming request to ProcessContext()
await _listener.GetContextAsync().ContinueWith(async (tsk) => {
    if (tsk.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) Debug.Assert(false);
    await ProcessContext(tsk.Result);
});
```

The first method requires an awkward closure to pass the context to the new Task, on that fact alone I tend to think the second method is better. I'm still new to async though, so I could be wrong.

The overall goal is to have a task that is continuously awaiting a result from GetContextAsync:

```
async Task Listen()
{
    while (_listener != null && _listener.IsListening)
    {
        // Use one of the methods above to get the context
        // and pass that context to a new task. This allows
        // the current task to loop around and immediately
        // resume listening for incoming requests
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is using `Task.Run` to offload `ProcessContext` to a `ThreadPool` thread. The second option doesn't do that. It simply completes `GetContextAsync` and moves on to execute `ProcessContext`.

However since `ContinueWith` wasn't meant to be used with async-await it will run synchronously until the first await and then both continue in parallel and return control over to the calling method (so don't mix `ContinueWith` and async-await)

It's unclear though why these are your options as you can simply invoke both methods and await the result:

```
var httpctx = await _listener.GetContextAsync();
await ProcessContext(httpctx);
```

It's very similar to using `ContinueWith` (when used correctly), but it's obviously simpler. Using `Task.Run` isn't really helpful here. It's mostly used for parallel code or offloading from the UI thread.

Comment: To expand a bit, I need to pass the context to a new Task so that the current Task (that executed GetContextAsync) can immediately call GetContextAsync again. Then I can put GetContextAsync inside a loop to constantly have a Task waiting for an incoming request. I added a bit more code to my question to illustrate.

Comment: @RileyGodard It seems you're looking for a dispatcher, right? `GetContextAsync` gets a context and then you want to fire `ProcessContext` and call `GetContextAsync` to receive the next one? If so then use your first option but without the awaiting the `Task.Run` task (and make sure **`ProcessContext` handles exceptions internally**)

Comment: What are the implications of `await`ing `Task.Run` in this situation? Curious.

Comment: @RileyGodard you mean not awaiting?

Comment: Yeah. I tested both `await Task.Run` and simply `Task.Run` and there didn't seem to be a difference.

Comment: @RileyGodard when you await it you wait (asynchronously, but still do not proceed forward) until that operation completes. That means you'll never have multiple `ProcessContext` happening at the same time. If you don't await then you can go right back to `GetContextAsync` but you aren't observing the calls to `ProcessContext` so if there's an exception for example you'll never know. That's why if you want to do this make sure you handle exceptions inside that method.

Comment: That makes sense. Last question; if the `ProcessContext` method is itself async, should the lambada passed to `Task.Run` be async as well? IE `Task.Run(async () => await ProcessContext(httpctx));`

Comment: @RileyGodard It can be. but it doesn't **need** to be as `ProcessContext` is already async and task returning by itself.

Comment: Cool. Thanks very much!